# For every prime $p > 3$ that is $3$ mod $4$, does $q+1 \mid p-q$ for some other prime $q$?

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

Yet another random conjecture about primes:

> Given a prime $p>3$ of the form $4n+3$. Then there exist a prime $q<p$ such that $q+1\mid p-q$.

Verified for all $p<100000$.

Comment: Did you check $p=3$ ?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15444/examples-of-eventual-counterexamples

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thanks! It was a bug in my program for $p=2,3$.

Comment: Your conjecture is equivalent to saying there exists $q<p$ such that $q+1 \mid p+1$.

Comment: @JasonM: yes much nicer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JasonM's observation is that the problem is equivalent to $q+1|p+1$. More generally, the fact that $p$ is prime is irrelevant because we just need to show there exists a $q$ for each $n$ such that $(q+1)|(4n+4)$. Trivially take $q=3$.